# opencv 2.4.6: can't open the webcam, invalid exception handler (Windows 7, VS2013)

Tags: opencv, handler, webcam

I have a problem in opening my usb webcam using opencv, actually I can't even open the webcam. For instance also the following code doesn't work:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(void){

    VideoCapture c(0);
}
```

The error has this form:
"First-chance exception at 0x775370CF (ntdll.dll) in blabla.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified."
I'm in debug mode (it has the same result in release mode) and i'm using pre-compiled opencv libs (that I guess had been compiled with VS2012). I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said in http://www.mattmontag.com/development/notes-on-using-opencv-2-3-with-visual-studio-2010

"If everything compiles and then you get runtime errors at the first instance of an OpenCV function call, something like this:

First-chance exception at 0x7c90e4ff in OpenCVHello.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.

This might be a bug in the OpenCV build, I don't know. You can disable it by going to Debug > Exceptions, unfold Win32 exceptions, and uncheck 0xC0000008."

Comment: Thanks for replying! I already tried that trick but it didn't work, the output was more or less the same:

"First-chance exception at 0x775370CF (ntdll.dll) in camera_capture.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.
First-chance exception at 0x7564812F in camera_capture.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x775370CF (ntdll.dll) in camera_capture.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.
"